# Find occurrences of conditional value from one column and count values from another column in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe containing userIds, week number, and a column X as shown below:

I am trying to group by the userIds if X is greater than 3 for 3 weeks.

I have tried using groupby and lambda in pandas but I am stuck

```
weekly_X = df.groupby(['Userid','Week #'], as_index=False)
```

```
UserIds Week  X
123      14   3
123      15   4
123      16   7
123      17   2
123      18   1
456      14   4
456      15   5
456      16   11
456      17   2
456      18   6
```

The result I am aiming for is a dataframe containing user 456 and how many weeks the condition occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get counts of values greater like `3` with aggregate `sum` and then filter values greater like `3`:

```
s = df['X'].gt(3).astype(int).groupby(df['UserIds']).sum()

out = s[s.gt(3)].reset_index(name='count')
print (out)
   UserIds  count
0      456      4
```

Comment: Very clean solution, however I am having trouble with it as the dataframe i'm working with is of type DataFrameGroupBy object. I have tried using .apply but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: @ramez - What is reason for it? Not necessary `weekly_X = df.groupby(['Userid','Week #'], as_index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

```
df_3 = df.groupby('UserIds').apply(lambda x: (x.X > 3).sum() > 3).to_frame('ID_want').reset_index()
df = df[df.UserIds.isin(df_3.loc[df_3.ID_want == 1,'UserIds'])]
```

Comment: What if the original dataframe I showed in the question was of type DataFrameGroupBy Object instead of a Dataframe?

Comment: Then, you can directly replace my “df.groupby('UserIds')” with  your groupby object

Comment: Or maybe you could upload your code of getting your groupby object